# How to call a function that is nested in python

Tags: python, function, nested

I'm trying to be able call a function that is nested.

```
def function1():
    #code here
    def function2():
        return #variable
def function3():
    x = #the variable that is returned in function2
    # I'm not sure how to get it to equal the variable that was returned in function2
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to *return* the function object; `function2` is just another local variable inside `function1` otherwise:

```
def function1():
    #code here
    def function2():
        return foo
    return function2

def function3():
    x = function1()()  # calls function2, returned by function1()
```

Calling `function1()` returns the `function2` object, which is then called immediately.

Demo:

```
>>> def foo(bar):
...     def spam():
...         return bar + 42
...     return spam
... 
>>> foo(0)
<function spam at 0x10f371c08>
>>> foo(0)()
42
>>> def ham(eggs):
...     result = foo(eggs + 3)()
...     return result
... 
>>> ham(38)
83
```

Note how calling `foo()` returns a function object.

Comment: Thanks! The examples helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To make that happen, you have to return `function2` from `function1` and then call `function2` from `function3` like this

```
def function1():
    #code here
    def function2():
        return #variable
    return function2

def function3():
    x = function1()
    print x()
```

Or, instead of storing `function2` in `x`, you can simply do

```
def function3():
    print function1()()
```

Comment: I have two nested functions inside function 1. how do I only call one of them? function1()(function2)

Comment: @user3133761 Try and avoid nesting functions as much as possible.

Comment: I know. Sorry :/ I need the variable from inside the one function though and I'm not sure how to make that variable available outside the function. This is kinda my first larger program.

Comment: @user3133761 Then put all of them together in a class :) So, that all the functions can share the data

Comment: would I just be able to call them like regular variables then? I think I may have already tried that, but I probably didn't do it right. I'll try it again.

Comment: @user3133761 You just have to address them with the object name. But thats okay, you ll get used to it. Just read the basics of OOP in Python, you would be ready to write larger programs like the one you are writing now :)